# Javascript Application to organize Folders

Tags: javascript, python, automation, directory, automator

In my current Job, we have a filing system for documenting all art made. I got tired of navigating the server, so I used MAC Automator to make an application. When folders ( The most I have done at one time is 18) are dropped onto it, it checks the folder name, and then files it in the correct spot on our server and then moves a copy into a backup folder on the device just in case (this backup folder is cleaned of anything more then 3 months old.)

Is there anyway I can set something like this up on a PC? I have a middling understanding of both Javascript and python. so Either language I could handle.

Comment: Apple’s Automator is only available in macOS, so you would need to refer to whatever automation or shell scripting utilities are available in the OS you are targeting.

Comment: I am using Windows, so I was searching for something for that OS